# Web services available to everyone?

Tags: json, web-services, http

Hi!

I have made a couple of web services that return a JSON response to the client when a POST request is sent to the server. However, the services can be accessed by anyone via URL, and was wondering if it is supposed to be this way, or should (if this is the case, then how?) the resources be hidden from general public?

For example, as it currently stands, i make an HTTP POST request from my android application to authenticate a user. However, the same request could be done by someone else using their browser, and then the browser would render the json back to them!

Also, if this is the way it's supposed to be, can i find authentication and other web services for websites like Facebook, Twitter etc ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Many websites with public APIs will make API keys available to those who identify themselves (ie, by signing up and becoming a developer, etc), to allow an **authorized request**. [Here's some information on how this is done with Twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request), for example.

Comment: Thank you. From this, i'm getting the understanding that i should incorporate some kind of Authorization key to my HTTP POST request, for example, when i'm registering a user from my android app. And then, from php, i can check if the key is the same as something i have stored to my server? In this case, if somebody tries to make a POST request from somewhere that isn't my android app to the same URL where my web service can be accessed, he won't be able to register a new user as he doesn't know the key ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Separately, you might also want to build in logic on the server that prevents 1,000,000 requests in a very short time, for example, which would help protect you if someone tries to use their key incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The rest API's themselves are available to the internet so yes they can are not 'hidden', but really it sounds like you want to restrict access to them to some subset of clients.

There are various methods to authenticate a user/client, hard to say what you need without knowing more.  Your post could contain a hashed password, a signature of the request data, it could be restricted by an SSL whitelist.

It depends on the needs of your application.

In order to lock it down you need to better describe the difference between a random guy with a browser, and your target client/audience.

Comment: If the web services are not hidden, how can I then ensure, for example, that some random dude won't make 1 000 000 POST requests to my registration form, thus filling my database with random users?

Comment: Using any one of the methods above to restrict access